# Harmony for python?

Tags: javascript, python, dom

Is there a Javascript and DOM environment like [Harmony](https://github.com/mynyml/harmony) for Python?

I want to execute Javascript on the DOM elements of a fetched/generated HTML. How can I do it in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that Harmony uses Johnson, which is a Ruby interface to Spidermonkey, and envjs, which is a pure javascript browser environment, you could probably use pyv8 (http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) to achieve the same effect.

Comment: There is also the [python-spidermonkey](https://github.com/davisp/python-spidermonkey) module. Which, do you think, would be better to implement it with?

Comment: @abhinav No idea. If you create something like this, I strongly suggest that you make it available via pypi.